# Javascript - For loop only affecting last element in array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a script that gives whatever you're pointing at (that has the class foxrainbowhover) an asynchronous rainbow effect.

I've got it working for the most part but unfortunately it, for some reason, only affects the last element inside of the array. I've ran it all through mentally several times but cannot find a single thing wrong with it. I'm hoping you'll be able to help. Here's what the effect should look like: https://jsfiddle.net/Laoderv6/

```js
(function(){let rainbowhover = document.getElementsByClassName('foxrainbowhover');
    let rainbowelements = [];
    let hoverinterval = [];
    let hovercounters = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < rainbowhover.length; i++) {
        rainbowelements[i] = spanElementContents(rainbowhover[i]);
    }

    //Set up the wavey effect with counters.
    for(let id = 0; id < rainbowelements.length; id++) {
        for(let i = 0; i < rainbowelements[id].length; i++) {
            hovercounters[id] = [];
            hovercounters[id][i] = 0 + i;
        }
        
    }


    // Add event listeners for every item classed foxrainbowhover.
    for(let id = 0; id < rainbowhover.length; id++) {
        rainbowhover[id].addEventListener("mouseenter", function startanimation() {
            console.log('hit');
               
            hoverinterval[id] = setInterval(() => {
                for(let i = 0; i < rainbowelements[id].length; i++) {
                    rainbowelements[id][i].style.color = 'hsl(' + (hovercounters[id][i] + Math.floor(i * 1)) + ', 100%, 70%';
                    console.log(rainbowelements[id]);
                    
                    hovercounters[id][i]++;

                }
            }, 8);






        }, false);



        rainbowhover[id].addEventListener("mouseleave", function stopanimation() {
            console.log('agh');

            clearInterval(hoverinterval[id]);
            for(let i = 0; i < rainbowelements[id].length; i++) {
                rainbowelements[id][i].style.color = 'black';
            }

            
            
        }, false);
    }
})()

function spanElementContents(element) {
    let spans = [];
    let chars = [];

    chars.push(element.innerText.split(""));
    for(let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        element.innerHTML = chars[i].map(function(char) {
            return '<span>' + char + "</span>";
        }).join('');
    }

    
    
    let temphtmlcollection = [].slice.call(element.children)
    for(let j = 0; j < temphtmlcollection.length; j++) {
         spans.push(temphtmlcollection[j]);
    }
    return spans;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="foxrainbowhover">test1</h1>
    <h1 class="foxrainbowhover">test111</h1>
    <h1 class="foxrainbowhover">test111111</h1>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will always cause an Exception:  `            hovercounters[id] = [];
            hovercounters[id][i] = 0 + i;`

Comment: 1. Why will it cause an exception?
2. Removing the counters doesn't solve the issue, so how is this related?

Comment: It will cause an Exception because you are trying to index the new array you created that has 0 items in it

Comment: I just tried it with strict mode on and it doesn't seem to be throwing an exception. I'm accessing an array I created and filling it, not attempting to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constantly resetting your array. You need to initialize it in the outer loop.
Change this:

```
for(let id = 0; id < rainbowelements.length; id++) {
    for(let i = 0; i < rainbowelements[id].length; i++) {
        hovercounters[id] = [];
        hovercounters[id][i] = 0 + i;
    }  
}
```

to this:

```
for(let id = 0; id < rainbowelements.length; id++) {
   hovercounters[id] = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < rainbowelements[id].length; i++) {
        hovercounters[id].push(i);
    }
}
```

or more simply:

```
or (let id = 0; id < rainbowelements.length; id++) {
  hovercounters[id] = rainbowelements[id].map((_, i) => i);
}
```

```js
let rainbowhover = document.getElementsByClassName('foxrainbowhover');
let rainbowelements = [];
let hoverinterval = [];
let hovercounters = [];

for (let i = 0; i < rainbowhover.length; i++) {
  rainbowelements[i] = spanElementContents(rainbowhover[i]);
}

//Set up the wavy effect with counters.
for (let id = 0; id < rainbowelements.length; id++) {
  hovercounters[id] = rainbowelements[id].map((_, i) => i);
}

// Add event listeners for every item classed foxrainbowhover.
for(let id = 0; id < rainbowhover.length; id++) {
    rainbowhover[id].addEventListener("mouseenter", function startanimation() {
        hoverinterval[id] = setInterval(() => {
            for(let i = 0; i < rainbowelements[id].length; i++) {
                rainbowelements[id][i].style.color = 'hsl(' + (hovercounters[id][i] + Math.floor(i * 1)) + ', 100%, 70%';

                hovercounters[id][i]++;
            }
        }, 8);
    }, false);

    rainbowhover[id].addEventListener("mouseleave", function stopanimation() {
        clearInterval(hoverinterval[id]);
        for(let i = 0; i < rainbowelements[id].length; i++) {
            rainbowelements[id][i].style.color = 'black';
        }
    }, false);
}

function spanElementContents(element) {
  let spans = [];
  let chars = [];

  chars.push(element.innerText.split(""));
  for(let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    element.innerHTML = chars[i].map(function(char) {
      return '<span>' + char + "</span>";
    }).join('');
  }

  let temphtmlcollection = [].slice.call(element.children)
  for(let j = 0; j < temphtmlcollection.length; j++) {
     spans.push(temphtmlcollection[j]);
  }
  return spans;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="foxrainbowhover">test1</h1>
<h1 class="foxrainbowhover">test111</h1>
<h1 class="foxrainbowhover">test111111</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when you use asynchronous functions inside a for loop. Here are a couple of ways to fix the problem:

- Use `let` instead of `var`
- Create a function that uses `closure` and returns a new function
- Use a `try catch` or `IIFE` block to create a new scope

### Let

```js
for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(index)
  }, 250);
}
```

### Function Wrapper

```js
for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  setTimeout(getFunction(index), 250);
}

function getFunction(index) {
  return function() {
    console.log(index);
  };
}
```

### Try Catch Block

```js
for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  try {
    throw index;
  } catch (index) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(index);
    }, 250);
  }
}
```

### IIFE Block

```js
for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  (function(index) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(index);
    }, 250);
  })(index);
}
```